# how to sync MSSQL table to MYSQL table by using SymmetricDS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

i want to MSSQL view data table(which is access in remostly) sync to the MySQL table witch located in my local computer by using SymmetricDS or any ather free method.can me explain the how to these task?

Comment: you can create one tool using python or java which can sync your databases.

Comment: i used php for development process.how do i manage it

Comment: Write the cron job which will run every day and sync the data with your code.

Comment: can you explain with more details

Comment: Create one python script which will read the data from MSSQL table and insert the data in mysql with INSERT INTO table (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1; and add a cron job in your system which run this python script every day

Comment: thank you .i will try it.but problem is my not good at python.can't write in php?

Comment: may be http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/ this can help you. If it is helpful, please upvote

Comment: sure bro.much appreciate your help.

Comment: Added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create one python script which will read the data from MSSQL table and insert the data in mysql with

```
INSERT INTO table (name, address, tele) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = 'Rupert' ) LIMIT 1;
```

and add a cron job in your system which runs this python script every day.

For PHP scheduler, [this](http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk) will help.

Comment: can help me to write python script